# my laptop wifi is not starting when i install linux mint 18

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

When I start Windows 10 my WiFi is working fine. But in Linux mint my WiFi is not starting.

In terminal when I check

```
rfkill list
```

It shows:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

When I want to check my current WiFi driver with:

```
lsusb
```

the list it showing is:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bb4:0003 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

my full system overview is
`System:    Host: kuntal-HP-14-Notebook-PC Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.2.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:   System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP 14 Notebook PC v: 0991100000000000000600087
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 220D v: 86.49 Bios: Insyde v: F.36 date: 12/18/2014
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4010U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 6784
           clock speeds: max: 1700 MHz 1: 1700 MHz 2: 1700 MHz 3: 1696 MHz 4: 1194 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.06hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-53-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000 bus-ID: 08:00.0
           IF: enp8s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Ralink RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe driver: rt2800pci v: 2.3.0 bus-ID: 09:00.0
           IF: wlo1 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (3.3% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST500LT012 size: 500.1GB temp: 45C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 55G used: 6.8G (13%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-2: /home size: 92G used: 910M (2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 8.50GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda9
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 52.0C mobo: 52.0C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 205 Uptime: 46 min Memory: 1383.3/3887.7MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.461) inxi: 2.2.35`

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the problem simple: on dual boot, your wifi connection works fine with Windows 10 and not with Linux Mint 18...

Some useful tips to troubleshoot your wifi in Mint:

[How to solve internet connection problems](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet)

Check the item 3:
no wired or wireless internet on a dual boot computer